# Uses of whatever after a clause

Tags: meaning-in-context

> bring my office all the Work progress Reports, whatever you have.

Is the placement of whatever correct or I should have placed either that or which?

Comment: Your use of "whatever" is correct and natural. Your use of capital letters, however, is unnatural

Comment: It is a parenthetical phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine, as an afterthought modifying reports.

There are other ways of doing it. Simplify the sentence and look at the options:

1. Bring me all the (Work Progress) reports, **whatever/any** (that) you have.
   (Whatever/any act as pronouns, referring to reports)
2. Bring me all the (Work Progress) reports (that) you have.
   (**that** acts as a conjunction. Here you cannot replace **that** with
   **which**.)
3. Of course, the simplest way of expressing it would be:
   Bring me whatever reports (that) you have.
   (Here **whatever** acts as a determiner.)
   but that doesn't answer your question.